# RuntimeException of a Tess4J based Java application

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, tesseract, ghostscript, runtimeexception

I am having a problem running a java program that utilizes the ***Tesseract-ORC*** engine via the ***Tess4J*** library. Basically, the program is for reading pdf files. The ***Tess4J*** related code in this program is as below:

```
Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
try{
    String text = instance.doOCR(file);
    if (!caseSensitive){
        text = text.toLowerCase();
    }
    output += filename + ",";

    // test if the text contains any keyword
    for (int j = 0; j < keywords.size(); j ++){
        String keyword = keywords.get(j);
        if (text.indexOf(keyword) >= 0){
            output += keyword + "|";
        }
    }                
    output += "\n";
    //System.out.println(text);
} catch (TesseractException e){
    System.out.println("Error reading the specified file! ...");
}
```

When I ran the program in the ***Eclipse*** environment, everything worked fine. Then I exported this program to a runnable jar (via packing required libraries into the jar file) and tried to run from the system command line (***Window*** 7 64-bit) by typing:

```
java -jar programname.jar
```

Then I got the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load library 'gsdll32': The spe
cified module could not be found.

Please download, install GPL Ghostscript from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gh
ostscript/files
and/or set the appropriate environment variable.
        at net.sourceforge.vietocr.PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Tiff(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(Unknown Source)

        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
        at app.KeyWordsChecker.main(KeyWordsChecker.java:137)
        ... 5 more
```

According to the error message, the program was having problem invoking `gsdll32.dll`. However, I have ***Ghostscript*** (v9.08) installed and the path to the `gsdll32.dll` file was added to the ***Path*** environment variable. In addition, I also included a separate `gsdll32.dll` file in the same folder with the `programname.jar` file, along side with `liblept168.dll`, `libtesseract302.dll`, and a "`tessdata`" folder. Could it be caused by running in a 64-bit ***Windows*** machine? But if that is the case, how come that the program worked fine in the ***Eclipse*** environment? BTW, in the ***Eclipse*** environment, the program was in fact invoking the separate `gsdll32.dll` file under the project folder, instead of referring to the counterpart under the ***Ghostscript*** program folder.

Great appreciation to any comments, suggestions, and solutions!

Comment: Which JVM and GS versions -- 32- or 64-bit -- are being used?

Comment: For JVM:
Java(TM) SE Runtime Evnironment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

For GS, it is gs9.08. I installed it on my 64-bit Windows machined, but the binaries (exe and dll) in the bin folder ended with win32.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue of library incompatibility. If you use JVM 64-bit, then all the libraries (DLLs) need to be 64-bit also. You will need to use the latest version of [Ghost4J](http://www.ghost4j.org/) to properly read latest Ghostscript vesion.

Comment: My code was calling the method from tess4j.jar. How do I incorporate Ghost4J?

Comment: Replace `ghost4j-0.3.1.jar` with .jar files for [Ghost4J](http://www.ghost4j.org/downloads.html) v0.4.5; using later versions would require changes to Tess4J due to the package name change.

Comment: Were you saying that I needed to change the source code of Tess4J to get it refer to the replaced .jar files from Ghost4J v0.4.5?

Comment: This is from Ghost4J site: Important: since version 0.4.6 root package was renamed from net.sf.ghost4j to org.ghost4j.

Comment: Thanks for specifying! I will look into it and post the news.

Comment: @DXZ, or use the latest release, v1.3.